# IASetIndexBuffer memory leak reason

Tags: c++, directx

For example, i run in loop this code:

```
m_device->CreateBuffer(&index_buffer_desc, &index_data, &buffer);
Release(buffer);
```

where m_device is ID3D11Device and buffer is ID3D11Buffer

Nothing leaks - i create object and then destroy it.

If i attach it to pipeline, like this:

```
m_device->CreateBuffer(&index_buffer_desc, &index_data, &buffer);
m_device_context->IASetIndexBuffer(buffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
Release(buffer);
```

than memory leaks starts.

MSDN says about IASetIndexBuffer that: "The method will not hold a reference to the interfaces passed in. For that reason, applications should be careful not to release an interface currently in use by the device."

OK. I reset index buffer after attach:

```
m_device->CreateBuffer(&index_buffer_desc, &index_data, &buffer);
m_device_context->IASetIndexBuffer(buffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
m_device_context->IASetIndexBuffer(NULL, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);
Release(buffer);
```

But memory steal leaks.

What is the reason? Where this object still sits?

Comment: How do you check if memory leaks? DirectX uses some internal references that may be disposed of eventually if there are no more external references.

Comment: Just looked at task manager - app grows 10mb/sec (specialy runned without vsync)

Comment: Try calling `ClearState()` and `Flush()` on the context afterwards. Btw, are you sure you need a new Index Buffer each frame?

Comment: I don't need, it's just for test. Really, i just restart this code and nothing happens, no leak. Nothing was changed. It was really strange behavior..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really, i just restart this code and nothing happens, no leak. Nothing was changed. It was really strange behavior.

Before post this question a always try to use ID3D11DeviceContext::ClearState method, but memory steal leaks.

Anyway, now all fine.